# Internet Explorer 8 ignores closing span tags and continues to apply styles

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have a few classes that adjust font sizing:

```
.text-tall {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

.text-small {
    font-size: .8em;
}
```

When I apply the class to a paragraph element

```
<p class="text-tall">Some text goes here.</p>
```

the styling work as expected. When I apply it to a span element

```
<p><span class="text-tall">Some text goes here.</span></p>
```

the adjusted `font-size` is applied to all text below the element on the page, sometimes resulting in progressively larger and larger text.

The obvious solution would be to simply always apply the class to the paragraph element, but my paragraph bottom margin is relatively sized (`margin-bottom: 1.5em`), so doing that increases the margin, too, which is something I don't want to do.

This only seems to be a problem in IE8 and lower. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: I have never heard of this happening, unless you have other messed-up HTML elsewhere. Can you show a live example?

Comment: Have you [validated](http://validator.w3.org/) your html? A live example would also help. Off the top of my head, this sounds like something that compatibility mode might do.

Comment: Validate your HTML!   See w3 online validation tool.

Comment: In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rsmbH/) it works perfectly. See the other comments for a reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the tips, everyone. Turns out a function in my `functions.php` file (in WordPress) was removing the ending `</span>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the `text-tall` div with the span in the CSS. For example, you could do this:

```
.text-tall span {
font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

You may also be able to do the same thing with the `text-small`.